# What Is A Browser Cache? What does it store from a webpage data?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching

Whenever I have an issue with a website, one of the first suggestions I will hear is “try to clear your browser cache” along with “and delete your cookies“. So what is this browser cache? What does it store and what is it good for?

I have googled. but didn't find the proper answer.I appreciate if anyone help on this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A browser cache "caches" (as in keeps local copies) of data downloaded from the internet. The next time your browser needs the same data it can get it from the cache (fast) instead of downloading it over the internet (slow)

The problem is that data can be old. For example imagine the browser cached www.nytimes.com today and 24hrs later you visited www.nytimes.com again. If the browser loaded the cached data it would be old news.

So there are [headers](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching?hl=en) (metadata) that the servers send to browser telling them how long they should cache something (if at all).

The data the browser generally caches are "requests" which. In other words if your browser asks for "http://foo.com/bar.html" the first time the browser will "request" that "foo.com" send it "bar.html". If the headers from "foo.com" are set a certain way the browser will the save a local copy of "bar.html". If you request the same thing again the browser may load "bar.html" from it's cache. I say "may" because it depends on the headers sent from the server. The server can say how long (say 10 minutes, 10 hours, 10 days, etc..) or it can say "don't cache this at all, always download the newest version".

If you go to your browser's dev tools (chrome shown below) and look at the network tab (not sure what it's called in other browsers). Load the page again and you can see all the requests. You'll also notice which ones were loaded from the cache

[image: network tab]

If you click on a request you can see the metadata from both the browser (request headers) and the server (response headers)

[image: jquery headers]

The reason clearing the cache often fixes things is if for some reason the server (a bug?) said it was ok to cache or used the cached version but the data on the server has actually been updated. The browser, doing what the server told it to do, is using its copy from the cache, not the newer version which is actually needed. There might also from time to time be bugs in the browser itself related to caching.

When everything is working correctly it's great but if one thing or another is mis-configured or sending the wrong headers then the browser can end up loading old data from the cache instead of downloading the newest data. Clearing your cache effectively forces the browser to download the data again.

You can find out the details of [what the various headers do here](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching?hl=en).

Comment: What sort of information cache will store.. lets say we have a grid with 1000 rows. does browser cache will store all that information?

Comment: A web browser can cache any of the data it downloads if the web site allows it.  This can include the HTML, CSS, pictures, video, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Browser caches are not mere rubbish bins but a mechanism to speed up the way we browse the web. Each website we visit has certain common elements like logos, navigation buttons, GIF animation files, script files etc. It doesn’t make sense for the browser to download each element (also commonly called as Temporary Internet files) when we hop from page to the other and back.

The page elements are downloaded when we visit a website and the browser checks its cache folder for copies when we browse the website.  If a copy exists, then the browser doesn’t download the same file again, thus significantly speeding up web browsing speeds.
for more info..
http://www.guidingtech.com/8925/what-are-browser-cache-cookies-does-clearing-them-help/

Answer (score 1):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_(computing)

First result in Google, this is the proper answer, but I will summarize =]

1) What is Browser Cache?
Cache is a component that stores data so future requests for that data can be served faster; the data stored in a cache might be the results of an earlier computation, or the duplicates of data stored elsewhere.

2) What does it store?
Web browsers and web proxy servers employ web caches to store previous responses from web servers, such as web pages and images.

3) What is it good for?
Web caches reduce the amount of information that needs to be transmitted across the network, as information previously stored in the cache can often be re-used. This reduces bandwidth and processing requirements of the web server, and helps to improve responsiveness for users of the web.

Comment: Does it store information that retrieved from databases.For example let say i have loaded 1000 rows. does it cache in web browser ?

Comment: It can, but that is not often what it is used for. As gman said, the headers in the webpage control what is cached, which is often UI elements on the page and their ordering. Data on the other hand, like a price on a website, need to be 100% accurate at the time the user visits the site, so this information is often not cached as to not confuse the user.